# Dynamic identity provider in identity Server

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver4, identity, duende

I'm using identity server in order to have a dynamic identity provider so i add
.AddIdentityProviderStore()
this line in order to reach my goal but with this line in login page i get all the identity providers registred in the database but when i try to connect with one of theme i get this error :

No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'google'. The registered schemes are: Identity.Application, Identity.External, Identity.TwoFactorRememberMe, Identity.TwoFactorUserId, idsrv, idsrv.external. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options => {
    options.ServerSideSessions.UserDisplayNameClaimType = "name";

    options.KeyManagement.SigningAlgorithms = new[]
    {
        // RS256 for older clients (with additional X.509 wrapping)
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256) { UseX509Certificate = true },
    
        // PS256
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSsaPssSha256),
    
        // ES256
        new SigningAlgorithmOptions(SecurityAlgorithms.EcdsaSha256)
        };
})
    .AddIdentityProviderStore<IIdentityProviderStore>()
    .AddServerSideSessions()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<UserIdentity>()
    .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
        b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    })
    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(defaultConnString, opt => opt.MigrationsAssembly(assembly));
    });
```